# Как устранить OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, .net, производительность, dump, outofmemoryerror

Произошло падение от OutOfMemoryException.

Как понять в чем проблема? Хочу разобраться какие вообще могут быть варианты, как их подтвердить и устранить. Прошу поправить если мои предположения не верны и дополнить полезной информацией.

Читал о таких ситуациях:

1) **[Отсутствует](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) требуемый непрерывный объем памяти.** 
[При этом свободной памяти еще может быть много](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/), просто она фрагментирована.

*Способ определить:* если не одна из последующих ситуаций не выявлена.

*Решение: ?(похоже что этим занимается CLR)*

2) **Физически не достаточно памяти для данной программы и программа написана не оптимально.**

*Способ определить:* Предположил что можно определить физический недостаток памяти посмотрев на монитор ресурсов(к примеру если нагрузка >90% - не достаточно памяти). Предположил что можно определить проблемы с производительностью с помощью дампа с кучей(хотя как это делать еще не знаю) или если знать узкие места системы.

*Решение: если узких мест не знаем - ждать второго падения и собирать дамп(какой инструмент порекомендуете для прод среды?), после менять код(оптимизировать, высвобождать неуправляемые ресурсы с помощью Dispose в проблемных местах)*

3) **Физически не достаточно памяти для данной программы и программа написана оптимально.**

*Способ определить:* из пункта 2.

*Решение: маcштабировать сервера.*

4) **Переполнение [StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=netframework-4.7.2).**

*Способ определить:* проследить за местами их использования StringBuilder.

*Решение: использовать конструктор StringBuilder() или менять логику программы.*

5) **Ограничение 32-bit only 2GB per object.**

*Способ определить:* Посмотреть диспетчером задач к примеру что x32 и что обьем памяти близок к 2GB. (Тут имеет значение битность OS или только сборка?)

*Решение: делать сборку 64-bit, или если это возможно поставить в app.config настройку gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"*.

Comment: Посмотри что в памяти лежит. В Rider есть вкладка для этого. В VS тоже должно быть что-то подобное.

Comment: Дмитрий Полянин, спасибо. Я думал что Rider и VS только вне прода способны на это (в режиме дебага или по уже созданному дамп файлу с кучей), но проверю.

Comment: Еще System.Drawing.Bitmap.Clone может бросать out of memory если просто не угадать с координатами (чуть-чуть выйти за пределы rect) - там криво выбран тип исключения. Еще может падать Out Of Memory если памяти не хватит для подгрузки сборки (видел ровно один раз, на проекте злоупотребляли аппдоменами с огромным количеством динамики)

Comment: Dispose и вообще работа с неуправляемыми ресурсами, кстати, к освобождению памяти не имеет никакого отношения. Неуправляемые ресурсы - это, в основном, handles, у них свои лимиты.

Comment: PashaPash, спасибо. Возможно я сейчас не прав, но похоже во время использования handles также возникает потребление памяти. И в случае их некорректной обработки также будет утечка памяти. Следовательно устранив некорректную обработку устраним и утечку памяти.

Comment: @AndreyMagnificent так можно любой объект притянуть к "при его использовании расходуется память :) В целом, кроме случая Bitmap.Clone, причина OutOfMemoryException всегда одна - вы попросили CLR выделить память, CLR выделить память отказалась. Причин может быть множество, при этом "фрагментация" и "Физически не достаточно памяти" - самые маловероятные (об этом прямо по ссылке в (1) сказано). Наиболее вероятная причина в случае x64 - закончилось место на диске / достигнут предел swap file. В случае x86 - просто уперлись в лимит 2Gb на процесс.